# Python: all index of list greater than x

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

```
data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60]
A_list=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
```

How do I find all the values in data that are above 50.
Next how do I print so that it displays

```
B:90 
D:80
H:60
G:70
```

Also I haven't used enumerate yet.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you please post some sample input and your expected output?

Comment: please post the code

Comment: You don't need the indexes to print those numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to print all the values higher then 50 a simple loop will do.

```
data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60]
for value in data:
    if value > 50:
        print(value)
```

---

If you need the indexes use this code. `enumerate` will give you an automatic counter.

```
data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60]
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    if value > 50:
        print(index)
```

---

If you need a list of indexes to print the values (your question is unclear at that point) then construct this list and loop over it.

```
data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60]
indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(data) if value > 50]
for index in indexes:
    print(data[index])
```

---

According to the question in your comment you could do the following (based on the last solution).

```
data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60]
characters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(data) if value > 50]
for index in indexes:
    print('{}: {}'.format(characters[index], data[index]))
```

This code uses the index for both lists.

If this is homework and you can't use `enumerate` you have to construct the indexes list with a standard `for` loop.

```
indexes = []
for index in range(len(data)):
    if data[index] > 50:
        indexes.append(index)
```

---

A pythonic solution would be something like this.

```
data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60]
characters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
for char, value in zip(characters, data):
    if value > 50:
        print('{}: {}'.format(char, value))
```

Comment: This helped! Now I have one more question. I have a second list lets say list1=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H] and if data = [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 40, 70, 60] how do I print B:90 , D:80,G:70, H:60

Comment: If my answered helped please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Could you answer it using the simple solution. Sorry I haven't gone over enumerate yet.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want the elements of the list which are greater than 50, you can simply use a list comprehension:

```
[el for el in lst if el>50]
```

where lst is your input list.

If you also wanted the index of those elements, you could:

```
[(i,el) for (i,el) in enumerate(lst) if el>50]
```

which would give you a list of tuples (index, element)

Answer (score 0):

You want an if loop; if x is greater than one of the numbers, print it?
example:

```
myList = list(range(0,100))

for numb in myList:
    if numb > 50:
        print numb
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what OP wants to do. But this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `enumerate()`, and you would like to store both the indexes of the numbers above 50 and the values themselves, one way would be to do it like so:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,50,51,3,53,57]
>>> b, c = zip(*[(d, x) for d, x in enumerate(a) if x > 50])
>>> print b
(6, 8, 9)
>>> print c
(51, 53, 57)
```

[Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) takes any object that supports iteration, and returns a tuple, `(count, value)`, when the `next()` method of the iterator is called. Since `enumerate()` defaults to start its count at 0, and increments the count by one each iteration, we can use it to count the index of the array that the iteration is currently on.

Now, our list comprehension is returning a list of tuples, if we were to print the comprehension we would get:

```
>>> print [(d, x) for d, x in enumerate(a) if x > 50]
[(6, 51),(8, 53),(9, 57)]
```

[Zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) creates a list of tuples when given two arrays, for example:

```
>>> f = [1, 2, 3]
>>> g = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(f, g)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

When used with the `*` operator, `zip()` will "unzip" a list.

So, when we "unzip" the list comprehension, two tuples are returned.

Hope this helps!